# Disable parameter based on selection of another parameter in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have two date parameters (date1 and date2) in my SSRS report..My requirement is that if user select date1 parameter then date2 parameter should be disabled for user and report should dispay data based on date1 parameter or vice versa.

Can anyone suggest me? how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible in a report that will be deployed to the report server. It may be possible in an ASP.NET solution. I'm having a hard time understanding why you would need the two date parameters, if only one of them will ever be used.